# Facebook Like button for every single post

Tags: facebook

Recently i get Facebook Like button from Facebook Developer page. I was my Site Like. But Now i want another like button for my every article. Is there any way to do that. Any one can tell me what is process to get Facebook like button for every article.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically each unique "like" needs to have a unique set of OpenGraph parameters in the `<head>` of the document.

I'd recommend using this link to make sure that Facebook does indeed pick up your site's information correctly: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

For an explanation of the openGraph tags, visit this one: http://ogp.me/

Good luck! :)